# Splitting Comma separated values of a column and converting into Columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, csv, oracle11g

I have a column in my table which contains comma separated values and I want to convert them into separate columns. I am not sure how many comma separated values I will get.

**What I have -**

[image: What I have -]

**What I need -**

[image: What I need -]

Comment: You mean, separate rows?

Comment: There are many [answers](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#safe=off&q=oracle%20convert%20delimited%20list%20to%20rows)  on the web.  Spend some time researching them.